# Контекст для окна/элемента WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как задать контекст для XAML окна?

**Исходные данные:**

есть модель `public class ModelClass {}`,

есть вью-модель `publilc class ViewModelClass: INotifyPropertyChanged {}`

Способ 1. В коде

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DataContext = new ViewModelClass();
}
```

Способ 2. В ресурсах окна

```
<Window x:Class="Instruments.Views.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WPF_APP.ViewModels"
    ...
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ViewModelClass />
</Window.DataContext>
```

А как еще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `MVVM Light` через локатор (а там уже через `IOC` контейнер)

```
 DataContext="{Binding EmployeeList_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Это все можно и без фреймоворка сделать.